# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams causing app crash in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layoutparams

I had a recycler view for which I have a linear layout as parent and a relative layout as child. I'm changing the layout params to these dynamically. My code is working pretty well for linear layout but when it comes to relative layout it is crashing.

It is not even showing the line number which is causing crash and after so many runs I figured out the line which is causing crash. This is the recycler view adapter class.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        ChatListItem listItem = listdata.get(position);
        LinearLayout parent=holder.parent;
        RelativeLayout chatView=holder.relLayout;
        holder.time.setText(listItem.time);
        holder.message.setText(listItem.message);
        if (!listItem.sentByCustomer) {
            int match_parent= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int wrap_content= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            chatView.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.incoming_normal));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parentParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(match_parent,wrap_content);
            parentParams.setMarginStart(5);
            parent.setLayoutParams(parentParams);

            int rel_wrap_content=RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rel_wrap_content,rel_wrap_content);
            relParams.setMarginEnd(50);




            chatView.setLayoutParams(relParams); // This line is  causing crash



        }
    }



    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        LinearLayout parent;
        RelativeLayout relLayout;
        TextView message, time;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            parent=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_view_parent);
            relLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_chat_view);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_chat_message);
            time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_time);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine the layout params belong to relative layout params and I'm setting them to a relative layout and I've also cross checked the xml file and that one is also a relative layout. Still the error log is saying it can't cast the linear layout params to relative layout params. Even the debugger is saying it as relative layout but why am I getting the error ? Here is the error log

```
07-04 15:09:13.609 5441-5441/com.motowala E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1071)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:8636)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1577)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:570)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:728)
                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6343)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
07-04 15:09:13.613 5441-5502/com.motowala D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=CustomerChatActivity, _si=6120152536016377641, timestamp=1499161153609, fatal=1}]
07-04 15:09:13.906 5441-5441/com.motowala E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.motowala, PID: 5441
                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1071)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:8636)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1577)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:570)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:728)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17641)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6343)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: May I know the reason why my question is downvoted ?

Comment: relLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_chat_view);
Check whether that id corresponds toa relativelayout

Comment: yes that corresponds to a relative layout. <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/customer_chat_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="50dp"

Comment: but that relative layout is inside a linear layout ? Does it cause an error like this ?

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says

> android.widget.**RelativeLayout**$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.**LinearLayout**$LayoutParams

You are trying to cast LinearLayout.LayoutParams into RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. Its just like trying to convert apple into orange.

Change this:

```
int match_parent= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int wrap_content= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
chatView.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.incoming_normal));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams parentParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(match_parent,wrap_content);
parentParams.setMarginStart(5);
parent.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
```

into this and try to run.

```
int match_parent= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int wrap_content= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
chatView.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.incoming_normal));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(match_parent,wrap_content);
parentParams.setMarginStart(5);
parent.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
```

Comment: You missed a line while reading question. The actual thing is this  int rel_wrap_content=RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rel_wrap_content,rel_wrap_content);
            relParams.setMarginEnd(50);

Comment: I'm setting rel_wrap_content to relative layout params not wrap_content which is a linear layout param

Comment: @bharath You should give parameters as your parent layout. If your Parent RelativeLayout, you should use RelativeLayout Params.

Comment: Thanks man perhaps that might be the reason behind that app crash. I resolved it by removing the root layout and making the relative layout as root

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

you're referencing linear layout but using relative layout, show the xml file you're using or check linear layout

Comment: No I'm using relative layout in xml   <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/customer_chat_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="50dp"

Comment: That relative layout is inside a linear layout

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by removing the root linear layout and making the relative layout as root. But still I'm clueless of the reason why the error has occured :(